REST API in Azure Data Factory to get access token for Power BI
I need to extract/export a excel file from a visual (table) in a Power BI report. I have found an option of export but if it is from a visual in a report just in PDF and ppx, not excel or csv. I found the only option is through an Rest API activity, but still can not even generate a valid access token with scope (can generate a token without scope, but does not work).
Now I am trying to access to the dataset and so on using Rest API in Azure Data Factory, but I can not generate a correct access token for a Bearer authentication.
The steps I have followed are:

Register an App in Azure Entra ID.

enter image description here

Give permissions

enter image description here

Then I have created a ADF activity to get the token

enter image description here

It is giving me a Token, but is it not creating a Scope, so this token is not working to get into de Power BI data.

So I have some suspicious why it is not working, that I have to create an authorization code before, however, I think the configuration is wrong, or maybe the permissions, I am not sure. Below is the confg, where I have tried to generate an authorization code, but still asking me for Application ID URI and Redirect URIs and a Code, that I dont know hot to create.
enter image description here
Does anybody know what is happening here?

Can you go to app.powerbi.com and try below additions, then re-try you rest api
additons 1:
Admin portal -> Developer settings -> Service principal can use Fabric APIs -> enable & Specify security groups -> select a Azure AD security group which
your service principal be included
additons 2:
Go to your workspace -> Manage access -> Add people or groups -> add the service principal

I'm not sure if need to add both at the same time, but in my environment both are added, and using rest api export works well. maybe one additions is sufficient, but not tested.

